# Neural Network and activation function

Tags: neural-network

I have dataset known as "Gas Furnace Data (Box and Jenkins, Series J)". I built up a form application and used sum net function and sigmoid activation function. My app fails and produce results always between 1 and 0. I made a little search ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7698/output-layer-of-artificial-neural-networks-when-learning-non-linear-functions-wi)) and found out that sigmoid function always produces output between zero and one. Here are some of sum functions and activation functions in picture below. I wonder which functions i should use here. As you see the datase, my inputs are between -3 and 3, and outputs are between 45 and 61. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks alot

[sum functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyE6C.png)
[activation func](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg4DW.png)

Answer (score 0):

one simple fix would be to add another function `f(x)=16*x+45` to the network output, so the new output would be between 45 and 45+6=61.

if the output is not strictly within (45, 61), but centered around say 53, you could try replacing the output activation function with simply `x+53`. and of course this can be learned by the bias term, but hard code some prior assumption would help learning.

Comment: It was the first thing came out to our mind but there is a thing in here, it will work so far the output data is between 45-61. But what if an input comes with an output higher then 61 at test data (normally we only know  outputs of train dataset, if its test data we dont know the output and expect machine to find it out via the help of his learning from train process.).

Comment: @Anka I see, so if there're no assumptions about the range of test data, the simplest way might be to just remove the output activation, or if you know that all the output will be say, above zero, you might use `max(x,0)` as the activation function. IMO the output activation function can be anything as long as it is differentiable.

Comment: @Anka if the output is not strictly within (45, 61), but centered around say 53, you could try replacing the output activation function with simply x+53. and of course this can be learned by the bias term, but hard code some prior assumption would help learning.

Comment: hi there, sorry to reply late, I connected to my supervisor and he said that i can normalize the outputs. Thanks alot.